# How do I create a custom HTML tag, without using customElement?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I need to create a custom HTML tag in JavaScript for Firefox. I cannot use `customElement.define()` because it is not a default class available in Firefox.

I am trying to use `document.registerElement`, but I don't think I am getting it right.

What is wrong with my code?

```
var My_weird_img = document.registerElement('weird-img', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});

My_weird_img.textContent = "I am a B img";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is you are changing the variable value not setting the text content of the element .
You need to grab the element first before you try to set it's value , Try this 
Html:

```
  <body>
    <weird-img>Ths is only a test</weird-img>
    </body>
```

Javascript:

```
var My_weird_img = document.registerElement('weird-img', {
prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});

document.getElementsByTagName("weird-img")[0].textContent;
```

Check the code [here](http://output.jsbin.com/yidinifozo) at JSBin
Full article [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)